# Regex: Match until "," but not if "," is inside brackets

Tags: regex, pcre

Given the following pattern:

```
group1: hello, group2: world
group1: hello (hello, world) world, group2: world
group1: hello world
```

of the style `<group_name>: <group_value>[, <group_name>: <group_value>[...]]`.

In general I use the following regex to extract the values:

```
group1:\s(?P<group1>[^,\n]+)(:?,\sgroup2:\s(?P<group2>[^,\n]+))?\n
```

which works file unless a `,` exists inside the `group_value`.

I know that this toyexample can be solved by something like:

```
group1:\s(?P<group1>.+?)(?:,\sgroup2:\s(?P<group2>.+?))?\n
```

However I do want to protect myself agains matching everything accidentally so I would still like to limit my match when it encounters a `,`.

**Question**: Is there a (general) way to match up to `,` and for that purpose ignore `,`s that are in brackets?

Comment: Maybe `group1:\s(?P<group1>.*?)(?::?,\sgroup2:\s+(?P<group2>.*))?$`? Actually, it is a variation of your second solution, what is wrong with that one?

Comment: Could you please do post expected output in your question, thank you.

Comment: the output i expect is the same as my toyexample. however i dont want to match too much by accident with `.+?`. i would like to at least stop on `,` when i encounter one.. unless inside of ballanced brackets.

Comment: Maybe something like `group1:(?P<group1>(?>[^,\n()]*(?:(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\)))?)*)(?:, (?P<group2>.*))?\n` https://regex101.com/r/rzH1NG/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pcre, you could make use of a recursive pattern for balanced parenthesis with [possessive quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).

you define the pattern for group 1, and if the same logic applies for group 2 you can recurse the subpattern defined in group 1.

As you exclude matching a newline in the negated character class, you might use `\h` to match horizontal whitespace characters instead of using `\s`

```
\bgroup1:\h+(?P<group1>(?:[^,\n()]*(?:(\((?:[^()\n]+|(?2))*+\)))?)*+)(?:,\h+group2:\h+(?P<group2>\g<group1>))?\R
```

- `\bgroup1:\h+` Match the word group1 and then `:` and 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(?P<group1>` Named **group1**

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `[^,\n()]*` Match optional chars other than `,` newline `(` or `)`
    - `(?:` Non capture group

      - `(\((?:[^()\n]+|(?2))*+\))` Match balanced parenthesis recursing **group 2**
    - `)?` Close group and make it optional
  - `)*+` Close the group and optionally repeat with a possessive quantifier (no backtracking)
- `)` Close group1
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `,\h+group2:\h+` Match group2: between horizontal whitespace chars
  - `(?P<group2>\g<group1>)` Named **group2**, recurse the subpattern in named *group1*
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional
- `\R` Match a newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qZF4yy/1)